# Connect IQ SDK COLOR_TRANSPARENT doesn't work?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I am trying to develop an App for my Garmin Vivoactive. When I am trying to paint a rectangle with a specific border color and a transparent fill color, the whole rectangle is in the border color. However regarding to the documentation COLOR_TRANSPARENT is a valid value.

My code looks like that:

```
<drawable-list id="Field" foreground="Gfx.COLOR_BLUE">    
    <shape type="rectangle" x="0" y="0" width="95" height="148" />
    <shape type="rectangle" x="100" y="0" width="95" height="148" color="Gfx.COLOR_TRANSPARENT" border_width="2" border_color="Gfx.COLOR_GREEN" />
</drawable-list>
```

Gfx is the synonym for Toybox.Graphics.

Instead of having a rectangle with a green border, I am getting a completely green rectangle. It occurs in the simulator as well as on the my device. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKONY.png)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 3):

That is a bug. I'm pretty active on the Garmin Forums and I have a test case for this that I've been meaning to post.

Your best option is to configure the layout to draw 4 lines instead.